# Receiving exception while starting Tomcat 9.0

Tags: java, class, tomcat, java-8, classpath

I am trying to start Tomcat 9 on my windows desktop using the command `java -jar bootstrap.jar`

However, I am getting an exception and my output looks as below:

```
C:\Program Files\Apache Software Foundation\Tomcat 9.0\bin>java -jar bootstrap.jar
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/juli/logging/LogFactory
        at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.<clinit>(Bootstrap.java:52)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.juli.logging.LogFactory
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(Unknown Source)
        ... 1 more
```

To resolve the error, I have tried to do the following but still it is not solved.

```
set CLASSPATH=%CLASSPATH%;.
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably it's the common tomcat class path issue in Wins: the path has the space(s) in it. Please install tomcat under say d:\tomcat9 to have a try.

BTW, it's not the proper way to startup a tomcat by command

```
java -jar bootstrap.jar
```

Please use the startup.bat script for Wins directly.

Comment: I am able to start using `use the startup.bat` however, I am also curious to know why `java -jar bootstrap.jar` is giving an exception. I have also verified that `LogFactory` is existing under the `tomcat-juli.jar`

Comment: Environments parameters and java options are pre-configured in batch script startup.bat. It might be the reason the ClassNotFound exception is thrown out. Actually you could trace the script to get some ideas.